# Remove item from nested array object in Javascript by key value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have object like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "first",
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "First section",
      "contents": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "title": "Sample title 1",
          "description": "<html>code</html>",
        },
        {
          "id": "124",
          "title": "Sample title 2",
          "description": "<html>code</html>"
        },
        {
          "id": "125",
          "title": "Some other sample",
          "description": "<html>code</html>"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Second section",
      "contents": [
        {
          "id": "126",
          "title": "Sample title 126",
          "description": "<html>code</html>"
        },
        {
          "id": "127",
          "title": "Sample title 127",
          "description": "<html>code</html>"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove specific object from contents array by its id (all those ids are unique).

I can easily find element I want to remove, but I'm unable to find in which section this element is to splice it later.

```
obj.sections.forEach(function(section) {
    section.contents.forEach((content) => {
        if (content.id == 125) {
            console.log(content)
            console.log(section)
        }
    })
})
```

In above code console.log(sections) returns undefined. How can I get position in sections array which contains contents array that has specific id. For example, id: 125 would return sections position 0, so I can use splice to remove that element.

If my approach is completely wrong please point me in right direction, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `.splice()`. `.filter()` will keep all items which you return `true` for and discard of those which you return `false` for. So, if the current section's content's object has an `id` equal to the one you want to remove you can return `false` to remove it, otherwise return `true` to keep that item. You can use this with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each section object to a new one with an updated contents array:

```js
const obj = { "id": 1, "name": "first", "sections": [ { "id": 1, "title": "First section", "contents": [ { "id": "123", "title": "Sample title 1", "description": "<html>code</html>", }, { "id": "124", "title": "Sample title 2", "description": "<html>code</html>" }, { "id": "125", "title": "Some other sample", "description": "<html>code</html>" } ] }, { "id": 2, "title": "Second section", "contents": [ { "id": "126", "title": "Sample title 126", "description": "<html>code</html>" }, { "id": "127", "title": "Sample title 127", "description": "<html>code</html>" } ] } ] };

const idToRemove = 125;
obj.sections = obj.sections.map(
  sec => ({...sec, contents: sec.contents.filter(({id}) => id != idToRemove)})
);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a simple filter for accomplishing the task. Also, it will be much cleaner and immutable way of doing it.

```
let newArrWithoutContentWithGivenId = obj.sections.map(section =>
     ({...section, contents: section.contents.filter(content => 
         content.id != 125)}));
```

Here, we are mapping each section whose content does not contain the ID 125. In short, `section > content.id != 125` will be removed from the new array.

Hope it helps :)

**Note: Code is not tested, it is just to help you find a way to do it cleanly.**

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the second argument of `forEach` :)

```
obj.sections.forEach(function(section, sectionIndex) {
    section.contents.forEach((content, contentIndex) => {
        if (content.id == 125) {
            // use the sectionIndex and contentIndex to remove
        }
    })
})
```